# How can I change label's text of one page from another php page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom

The problem is: I'm building a simple log-in php page, the user should enter the username and password and click "Login" button. This button submits the entered values to another php page that deals with the database and makes sure that the user is registered. Now if he/she is not registered, then the page return to the log-in page, but before that, it changes some label's text to inform the user that the entered username or password are wrong.

My problem is that: the second php page don't have access to the first one's elements!

Here are the codes I used till now!
Second php page: called LoginSubmit.php:

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=../Home.php'>";
}
else
{
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo"parent.document.getElementById('FailureText').innerHTML = 'Yours user name or password are wrong!!';";
echo "</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=../Login.php'>";
}
```

And at the first page (called Login.php), the label is defined in the form like:

```
<td align="center" class="LiteralProb" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
    <label ID="FailureText"></label>
</td>
```

It's empty and seems non-existing label, but when log-in error occur, a message to the user should be displayed on it!

Any help, Please! :) ??

Comment: You do want to check out AJAX. Or handle everything in one script and reload the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value as some sort of "*flash message*" in the session. In `LoginSubmit.php` use:

```
// at the top of your script
session_start();

// when you know an error occurred
$_SESSION['failure_message'] = 'Yours user name or password are wrong!!';
```

And on the other page use:

```
// at the top of your script
session_start();

// in your HTML part
<label ID="FailureText">
    <?php print ( isset($_SESSION['failure_message']) ? $_SESSION['failure_message'] : '' ); ?>
</label>

// at the bottom of your script remove the value from the session again
// to avoid that it's displayed twice
unset($_SESSION['failure_message']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your login page is anything but simple ;-)

How about this?

```
if (!$validLogin) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/login?err');
    exit;
}
```

... and:

```
<? if( isset($_GET['err']) ){ ?>
    <div>Invalid username/password</div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be done in some different ways:

1- You could use session variables to store the values you want to share between php scripts:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['val1']=$value1; //set the value
```

You retrieve it like this:

```
//receive on the other script
session_start();
$value1=$_SESSION['val1'];
```

2- You can pass a variable using GET (the URL) when sending the user to the login script.

```
header("location: first_script_url?error=some_error_message");
```

You retrieve it like this on the login script:

```
$err_msg=$_GET['error'];
```

3- You can do the login process using AJAX, so instead of redirecting the user from one script to the other, you make a call to the second script, and depending on the second script return value you tell the user if there was any error:

using Jquery, better use POST if we're passing user info, also it would be better to use HTTPS (you should do this regardless of the method you choose), or at least use a encryption function on the password (this is not 100% safe):

```
$.post("second_url.php", {user: username, pass: password}), 
function(data){
     //data contains anything second_url.php echoed. So you want to echo a 1 for example if everything went ok.
     if(data == 1){
           //OK
     }else{
           //Something went wrong, show the user some error.
     }
});
```

The user will never leave the first script, so you have all the variables in your javascript/Jquery.